# Moshi's Custom Adapter with RxAndroid & Retrofit & Kotlin

Tags: android, rx-java, kotlin, retrofit2, moshi

After configuring Kotlin for Android project, I wrote a simple `MainActivity.kt`. It called Retrofit to get a JSON file which contained the following data:

```
{
    "message": "success",
    "user": {
        "username": "Eric"
    }
}
```

Now I want to use Moshi to convert the JSON data to Kotlin's class, so here are the two classes to reflect the above JSON structure:

```
class User(var username: String)

class UserJson(var message: String, var user: User)
```

And a custom type adapter for Moshi:

```
class UserAdapter {
    @FromJson fun fromJson(userJson: UserJson) : User {
        Log.d("MyLog", "message = ${userJson.message}")  // = success
        Log.d("MyLog", "user = ${userJson.user}")        // = null

        return userJson.user
    }
}
```

When it goes into the function `fromJson()`, `userJson.message = "success"` as expected. But the strange thing is that `userJson.user` is `null`, which should be `User(username="Eric")`.

I am new to Moshi and Kotlin, and I have already stuck with this problem for about 10 hours. Please help me out. Thanks for any help.

========================================

The following is the entire code of `MainActivity.kt` (50 lines only):

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Custom Type Adapters for Moshi
        val userMoshi = Moshi.Builder().add(UserAdapter()).build()

        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/")
                .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(userMoshi))
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build()

        val accountService = retrofit.create(AccountService::class.java)

        accountService.signUpAnonymously()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe { user ->
                    Log.d("MyLog", user.toString())
                }
    }
}


// ========== For Retrofit ==========
interface AccountService {

    @GET("u/17350105/test.json")
    fun signUpAnonymously() : Observable<User>

}


// ========== For Moshi ==========
class User(var username: String)

class UserJson(var message: String, var user: User)

class UserAdapter {

    @FromJson fun fromJson(userJson: UserJson) : User {
        Log.d("MyLog", "message = ${userJson.message}")        // = success
        Log.d("MyLog", "user = ${userJson.user}")              // = null

        return userJson.user
    }

}
```

The `build.gradle` is:

```
compile "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.0"
compile "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.0"

compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0"

compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0"
compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:2.1.0"
compile 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0'
```

Thank you again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can solve the problem by changing your code to do something like below.

Basically in your case when the `UserAdapter` is registered, it tells moshi that it can create a `User` only from `UserJson` object. Hence Moshi does not recognize the JSON object with keyword `user`.

By adding an indirection in form of `User1` (please pardon the naming convention), the `UserJson` is created properly with `User1` from JSON.

```
class User(var username: String)

class User1(var username: String) // I introduced this class
class UserJson(var message: String, var user: User1) // changed User to User1

class UserAdapter {
    @FromJson fun fromJson(userJson: UserJson): User {
        println("message = ${userJson.message}")        
        println("user = ${userJson.user}")              
        return User(userJson.user.username)
    }
}
```

Comment: It works, thanks! I have an additional question: Is there any better way to achieve the same goal? (The only thing I need to do is to get the `user` field from the original JSON.)

Answer (score 5):

If you just need the `User` object. There is a library called [Moshi-Lazy-Adapters](https://github.com/serj-lotutovici/moshi-lazy-adapters) that provides a `@Wrapped` annotation, that allows specifying the path to the desired object. All you have to do is add the respective adapter to your Moshi instance and change the service code to:

```
interface AccountService {

  @GET("u/17350105/test.json")
  @Wrapped("user")
  fun signUpAnonymously() : Observable<User>
}
```

No need for any other custom adapter.

Comment: Just saw some related issues in Moshi's GitHub page (#182 #176 #113). Thanks so much for your Moshi-Lazy-Adapters!

Comment: Just to complement the answer, you should define the Adapter like this ".addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(Moshi.Builder().add(Wrapped.ADAPTER_FACTORY).build()))" in the retrofit builder. And if you need a deeper path "@Wrapped(path = ["a", "b", "c"])"